# Going back to previous version (say May 2023) fails

Tags: powerbi

I was using the September 2023 version of PowerBI, and the whole way you have to create measures (at least on my screwy install) is a super pain. I'd really like to go back a few releases (which used to be stupid easy), and just use that.
(Would be really nice if MSFT stopped trying to catch up with the competition and just released a less buggy product!)

But after I uninstall PowerBI and PBI Report Builder, it won't let me install, claiming I have a newer version installed. This is a new error I've never seen, and I've been uninstalling PowerBI for most of 10 years.

How do I utterly and completely uninstall PowerBI? Do I have to remove SqlBI gang's stuff too? That seems like overkill.

Uninstalled PowerBI,
Uninstalled PowerBI ReportBuilder.
Rebooted.

I expected it to install correctly, but no joy. "A later version of PowerBI is already installed..."